# How do I serve JSON files with proper mimetype and not text/plain?

Tags: node.js, json, express, nginx, mime-types

I am trying to use a manifest.json file, which refuses to work if the type isn't set to application/json.

I have a nginx server running node/express.

I put the manifest.json in my public folder and the server reads the type as text/plain, and throws an error.

Under `/etc/nginx/config/` there is already a line that reads:

```
application/json                      json;
```

I even tried serving the file with express and specifying the header:

```
var manifest = fs.readFileSync('routes/manifest.json', 'utf8');
router.get('/manifest.json', function(req, res) {
    res.header("Content-Type", 'application/json');
    res.json(manifest);
});
```

And that still reads it as text/plain.

I'm guessing it's something I need to do with nginx, but all the suggestions I've found talk about files I don't have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the `fs` module reads your existing `manifest.json` file, it is converting it into one large utf-8 string, instead of actual JSON.

To the human eye, it looks like regular JSON, but it’s actually just a bunch of JSON inside a string.

To the server, it just sees the string and sets the mime type as it should, as `text/plain`, since it technically is.

You could try replacing `res.json(manifest);` with `res.send(JSON.parse(manifest));`, which should take the value that `fs` got from `manifest.json`, and attempt to convert it to properly formatted JSON with the proper mime type.